# GridView not fit properly under Gallary

Tags: android, gridview

In my main screen, I have a `Gallery`, `TextView` and a 3 x 3 `GridView`, the `Gridview` is under the `Gallery` and `TextView`, now the `GridView` is suppose to fit properly on all screen sizes, am using **s grand duos** and **s3** to test. 
It renders well on the s3, but on the grand duos it does not, on the grand duos all the vertical spacing are joined together and you have to scroll the `Gallery` to view the last row of the `Gridview`.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="100" >

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=" Swipe to view image"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:columnWidth="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>






public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.upcoming,
        R.drawable.news,
        R.drawable.special, 
        R.drawable.live, 
        R.drawable.acts, 
        R.drawable.blogs, 
        R.drawable.resources,
        R.drawable.profile, 
        R.drawable.apps, 
  };

  // Constructor
  public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(190, 190));
    return imageView;
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You give android:weightSum 100 but in text you take its height. You have to adjust this weight in all child og linear layout, like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="120" >

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height=" 0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text=" Swipe to view image"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:columnWidth="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this doesnt work, on my grand duos, the gridview is still scrolling and it doesnt take the whole screen properly, i really dont want the grid view to be scrollable and the vertical spacing doesnt show on the grand duos its still joined together

Comment: then take a margin bottom something in grid view just try this

Comment: it gave it a space at the bottom but its still scrolling, what i actually want is the GridView to fit in properly the way it does on the s3

Comment: no dude grid view native property is scroll able when ever it will not fit on screen so try to stop scroll with custom grid view :)

Comment: wow, thanks alot for that information, that helped alot, but what about the vertical spacing that disappears from my gridview in my grand duos, but shows on my s3. i want that vertical spacing to show same way in my duos

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. I hope it helps someone else who has a similar issue. I changed this line in my `ImageAdapter`:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(190, 190));
```

to

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```